# Recognizing button click

Tags: android

i have set up button1 as with id button and button two with button2 id.

Now here is what happening that is going out of my mind i placed this code and called a switch statment for each button under `onButtonClick(view v)`
but when i'm clicking any button the same thing is happening either on this code addition is happening for the both buttons.

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {


    TextView tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultT);
    EditText e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fNum);
    EditText e2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sNum);
    TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    int numF = Integer.parseInt(e1.getText().toString());
    int numS = Integer.parseInt(e2.getText().toString());
    int sum = numF + numS;
    int mux = numF * numS;


    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button: {
            tx.setText(Integer.toString(mux));
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(mux));
        }
        case R.id.button2: {
            tx.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
        }
        break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("an error has occurred");
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You must add a break statement after each switch case**

If there are multiple switch cases in a row with no break statement then the last case with a break will be executed no matter which case is matched in that sequence of cases.

Modify your switch block as given below:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button: 
            tx.setText(Integer.toString(mux));
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(mux));

        break;
        case R.id.button2: 
            tx.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
            t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));

        break;
        default:
            throw new RuntimeException("an error has occurred");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added `break` statement after case `case R.id.button:` that's why  `case R.id.button2:` executed always.

**Update your `switch-case` block as below:**

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button: {
        tx.setText(Integer.toString(mux));
        t1.setText(Integer.toString(mux));
    }
    break;
    case R.id.button2: {
        tx.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
        t1.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
    }
    break;
    default:
        throw new RuntimeException("an error has occurred");
}
```